# How to show Adsense Ads only on mobile,tablets,etc (Hide on Desktop)

Tags: php, jquery, css, mobile, adsense

I have recently redesigned my website to a responsive design and everything is working great. The only issue is, the current desktop ads are incompatible with the responsive design. I have discovered a method to hide the desktop ads on mobile, but can;t seem to find a way to only show responsive ads on mobile,tablets,etc (anything but desktop) so that I can create new ad positions for these. My current adsense code is in the format

```
<script async src="//"></script>
<!-- MH Responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it, I would use PHP code. Here is the code:

(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    '; } }?>

Place that script at the top of the page and when you want to show the ad just paste this script:

Comment: Excellent, this is doing exactly what I needed it to do. My question is though, I may need to call this script several times/page. Would this long script cause slow load times or any other issue/conflict? Thanks again. Regards

Comment: You could define a function. But the script will slow down the page by a fraction of a second. I edited my answer with the function version.